# (Java) How can I skip a space when reading from a file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to save words, their parts of speeches, and definitions to a file when I exit the code and then read them back when I reopen the code the next time. This is my save line:

```
WordListPrinter.println(name + " " + partOfSpeech + " " + definition);
```

This is my read code

```
while(readFromFile.hasNextLine()){
            String name = readFromFile.next();
            String POS = readFromFile.next();
            String definition = readFromFile.nextLine();
}
```

Each time I run the code, it adds a space to `definition`, because the `String definition = readFromFile.nextLine();` part reads the `" " + definition` from the save line. I tried

```
while(readFromFile.hasNextLine()){
            String name = readFromFile.next();
            String POS = readFromFile.next();
            String useless = readFromFile.next();
            String definition = readFromFile.nextLine();
}
```

to get rid of the space, but it removed the space and the first word of the definition. I also tried `char useless = readFromFile.next().charAt(0);`, but that just saved the space to `useless` and removed the first word of the definition anyways. Is there a way for me to scan and remove the space without removing the first word?

Comment: What about `readFromFile.nextLine().trim()`?

Comment: Would I use that to save the string to `useless`?

Comment: `trim()` returns a new String without spaces at the beginning/end. Try saving it to `definition`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Should you add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" comes from mixing `next()` with `nextLine()` invocations, and is "expected behavior". ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html))

To get rid of the blank:

- You could (if applicable) consistently us `next()` (without `nextLine()`)
  , so:

  ```
  String definition = readFromFile.next();
  ```
- [String.trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) is "never wrong" (to remove trailing white space from a string):

  ```
  String definition = readFromFile.nextLine().trim();
  ```

Comment: Using `next()` didn't work because the definition is more than one word long, but `trim()` worked. Thanks